# Floating text from parent div over two side-by-side child divs?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm not sure if I am overthinking this, but I have a website where I have a section that is organized like this:

```
<div id="parent">
<p>Some Text</p>
  <div id="child1"></div>
  <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

`#child1` and `#child2` have no content, but only background-images that are of equal size. What I want to do is centrally float the text over the two div elements.

On this page, as background-image sizes cannot set the size of the container, I use a quick JS solution to set the height of the div based on the aspect ratio of the image. This is working here, but I can't figure out how to have the text over the child divs rather than before them.

Edit: Here's an example image, the two colors represent two different background images.
[image]

Comment: Can you add a fiddle with your markup and css

Comment: Can you provide some image that shows what your final output should look like? It's not so clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can display your images as `inline-block` so they will be at the same line and use `text-align: center` to center all your content inside your `#parent` div.

```css
#parent{
  text-align: center;
}

.image{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
}

#child1{
  background-image: url("https://pstbqpil.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/seagull-in-the-foreground-robert-moses-bridge-in-the-background-vicki-jauron.jpg");
}

#child2{
  background-image: url("http://betterphotography.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/890362_56513892.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<p>Some Text</p>
  <div id="child1" class="image"></div>
  <div id="child2" class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option you can use:

```css
#parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#child1 {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/200x400/F00/FFF);
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#child2 {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/200x400/0F0/FFF);
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#parent p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<p>Some Text</p>
  <div id="child1"></div>
  <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The demo below is using the position absolute method.

```
<div id="parent">
  <p class="text">Some Text</p>
  <div id="child1"></div>
  <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

everything is wrapped in the Parent div so you can move that about as you like.

Just replace the background colours with the URL link in the CSS.

Hope this is what you're looking for! :)

https://jsfiddle.net/xf87jgLq/45/